# Can't seem to get tensorflow's "tflearn.objectives.roc_auc_score (y_pred, y_true)" to work

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am *very* new to tensorflow but I am trying to use their "tflearn.objectives.roc_auc_score (y_pred, y_true)" function to compute auc. **The reason why I am using this specific one is because the objective function directly optimizes AUC**.

This is the code I have as a proof of concept:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
y_true = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0])
y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
print("sklearn auc: {}".format(roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)))

import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
auc = tflearn.objectives.roc_auc_score (y_scores, y_true)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print("tf auc: {}".format(sess.run([auc, update_op])))
```

This gives me

```
sklearn auc: 0.25
tf auc: [1.0395000000000003, 0.74999976]
```

And when I make the following changes

```
y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
```

I get the **same** number for my AUC. I'm assuming that the second element in the list (0.74999976) is the AUC

```
sklearn auc: 0.75
tf auc: [0.01562500000000001, 0.74999976]
```

Needless to say, I do not trust the AUC numbers I am getting. The documentation for the AUC can be found here http://tflearn.org/objectives/

I am using tensorflow 1.10. Any help or insight will be appreciated. Thank you